# Azure Table Storage: How to save multiple copies of the same data in a reliable way

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage

I need to save multiple copies of the same data in `Azure Table Storage` with different **row keys** so that I can query different sort orders because `ATS` does not support secondary indexes. However, I'm not sure how to go about doing this in a reliable way.

If I attempt to save multiple copies back to back in the same back-end code, I fear that if one transaction goes through, the next one might fail. What is the recommended approach to solving this problem? I considered using an `Azure Functions` trigger, but I'm not sure if `ATS` has triggers for this purpose (i.e. insert/update/delete) unlike `Cosmos DB` and its `Change Feed`. I'm trying to avoid `Cosmos DB` because I find it quite expensive in terms of transactions and storage.

Comment: what is the problem you are really trying to solve? When you call the Table API to write a new entry, you get the result - if the write succeeded or not. In the off chance that it doesn't (and maybe your experience is different, but I have never really seen issues there), you can either not do the second write, or retry, or delete the first entry again?!

Comment: Unfortunately Entity Group Transactions only support transactions within the same table and same partitionKey. There's no out of the box solution for your scenario. You will need to implement a retry/rollback mechanism yourself. You could offload this process to a background worker that will bundle both inserts and make the second insert only when the first one succeeds or delete the previous.

Comment: As I mentioned, I need to query the same table with different columns in the predicate. Since there is no secondary index support in ATS, I was thinking of making multiple copies of my data. I can implement my own retry mechanism, but what if the rollback itself fails when I can't write the second entry and decide to remove the first entry? I know this is low probability, but it could potentially still happen...

Comment: Is there an Azure Functions trigger that gets run after a row is inserted/updated/deleted in ATS? I can write one entry directly and have the trigger write the second entry. If the second entry fails, the trigger fails and needs to resume from the same checkpoint. This seems more reliable to me. I'm just not sure if ATS supports Functions triggers.